# jquery .animate() called on click anywhere on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate, inputbox

I have the below jquery. It all works correctly except.... if I input a value in "name=bidz" and then click anywhere on the page, this triggers the animation but nothing else. How do I get clicks outside of my submit button to stop triggering the animation?

Does this have something to do with first clicking in the input box, then adding the value, and then the follow click is a second change?

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div id="<?php echo $this->item['id']; ?>">
        <div class="ab">
            <label for="ab_input"><?php echo $this->translate('To get the auction started, you must enter a starting bid.'); ?></label>
        <span class="auction_bid_container">
            <input id="ab_input" type="text" maxlength="12"
                   class="middle nmr event-clear-focus"
                   name="bidz" value="Enter something" />
            <input id="updateBidButton" type="submit"
                   class="button grey-button num-items-button"
                   name="bidz" 
                   value="<?php echo $this->translate('submit'); ?>"/>
        </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<div class="clear mb20"></div>



$('input[name="bidz"]').live('change', function () {
    var bidz = this.value;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "?module=is&controller=index&action=syy",
        dataType: "text",
        data: 'bid=' + bidz + '&id=' + id,
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('.ab').animate({
                'backgroundColor': '#ffdead'
            }, 400);
        },
        success: function (result) {
            if (result == 'ok') {
                console.log(bidz);

                $('.ab').animate({
                    'backgroundColor': '#A3D1A3'
                }, 300);
            } else {
                $('.ab').animate({
                    'backgroundColor': '#FFBFBF'
                }, 300);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Where is `input[name="bid_amount"]`  in your html code, As per your htmk you have `input[name="bidz"]`

Comment: Sorry @SuperUser, I had changed bid_amount to bidz.

Comment: @ian What is the version of your `jQuery` ?

Comment: @DavidR It is an older version - 1.8.1. I need to update but haven't bitten that off b/c there is so much legacy code.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want clicks outside of your submit button to stop triggering the animation, then you should attach the event handler to your submit button instead of text input. Something like this should work fine:

```
$('#updateBidButton').live('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var bidz = this.value;
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: "?module=is&controller=index&action=syy",
    dataType: "text",
    data: 'bid=' + bidz + '&id=' + id,
    beforeSend: function () {
        $('.ab').animate({
            'backgroundColor': '#ffdead'
        }, 400);
    },
    success: function (result) {
        if (result == 'ok') {
            console.log(bidz);

            $('.ab').animate({
                'backgroundColor': '#A3D1A3'
            }, 300);
        } else {
            $('.ab').animate({
                'backgroundColor': '#FFBFBF'
            }, 300);
        }
    }
});
});
```

**Edit:**

Also please remember that `live()` method was removed in jQuery 1.9, so consider replacing it with:

```
$(document).on('event', 'yourSelector', function() {
    // your code hear
});
```

So in your case it would be:

```
$(document).on('click', '#updateBidButton', function() {
    // ...rest of your code...
});
```

This will attach an event to the document object and then when you click an element it will check if the target is *#updateBidButton*, so it will work even if the html is generated dynamically.

Comment: Tx @Fuross. The reason I went away from the '#updateBidButton' selector is because the function wouldn't work on safari and firefox. When I used the 'input[name="bid_amount"]' selector, as I had successfully done on other jquery functions, it worked on all 4 major browsers. Any ideas on what was going on there or how to fix?

Comment: @ian I can't tell you much without seeing the actual code, there might have been some compatibility issues because of using a really old version of jQuery with new web browser but this is unlikely, also which event did you use on the button? onchange? onclick? If you could provide me a JSFiddle with all the code I could tell you more.

Comment: @ian Also, I assume the code edited by me and provided in my answer, works fine for you in all browsers?

Comment: @Faross,  still trying to get your code to work.  Previous effort that worked in chrome/ie but not safari/firefox is something like this:  [Jsfiddle] (https://jsfiddle.net/kanyamyb/2/)

Comment: I can give you a live test case if that would help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154699/discussion-between-ian-and-fuross).